# Opening facebook share dialog with populated text and url from a web-app via intent?

Tags: ios, facebook, web

I've been searching on Google, GitHub and StackOverflow for 2 days before I'm asking this question, but all the answers are old and outdated so I couldn't solve the problem.

For Twitter, Pinterest and Google+ I found the URL intents and they work just fine. So for example if I click this URL `twitter://post?message=${fullMessage}` in Safari, the native Twitter share dialog is opened with the link and the message.

Is there any documentation (from 2015-2016) that will work for the native Facebook iOS app in the same way?

Thanks!

Comment: prefilling is not allowed, you should read the platform policy

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Comment: @luschn ok can I at least open the share dialog with the url?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Comment: @luschn this still does not explain how to open the share dialog of the native Facebook APP via from a webpage.